# How to render the browser error 404 with nodejs

Tags: node.js, error-handling, http-status-code-404, render, default

It may sound really stupid but is it possible to render the default browser error page with NodeJS?
All I found on the internet, is to make personalized content (a simple text <res.send('Page not found')>, a blank page <res.end()> or a custom page) but not the default page of the browser. And if I do not return a response, the browser waits until timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Firefox doesn't have a default 404 page (despite it has an unavailable page when accessing a random non-existing website, which is different error).

Assuming you're using Express, the simple response code that you may have seen :

```
res.status(404).end();
```

makes Chrome (Chromium 107.0.5304.87) displaying its own error page as expected, but not firefox (107).

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e2f5984e-3efd-4b67-bb09-5c7c356c3477/returning-404-from-controller-displays-empty-page-in-firefox?forum=aspmvc) is a bit outdated, but seems still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you could just send a plain text like:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
res.type('text/plain'); // set content-type
res.send('Error 404'); // send text response
});
```

Comment: In fact, I would like to avoid that. I have several domain names pointing to the same server which some have not yet visual identity.
And until we have webdesigners on the project, I would like there is nothing, as if no domain has been reserved.
But in fact it is more a technical question: is it possible to return the default browser error 404 page?